# Wheat-based gluten-free pie crust?

Tags: flour, gluten-free, crust, wheat

I am trying to find a way to make a pie crust, with wheat flour, that's somehow gluten free. I only have one idea: reverse creaming, but with a pie crust. However, I know that gluten will still slowly develop if I mix it, so I was wondering if there were any better methods.

Is this at all feasible?

Comment: You are aware that no matter what you do to wheat, it will always contain gluten. Gluten is a natural protein in wheat and related grains. When recipes talk about "developing the gluten" they aren't making it, just merely getting the gluten protein molecules to bind together.  You can not call anything made with wheat gluten-free, and most certainly can't feed it to people with coeliac disease.

Comment: @bob1 I'd say that comment would be a sufficient answer to this question if you posted it as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Gluten sensitivity” is actually a sensitivity to gliadin, a precursor to gluten found in wheat flour. Even when the dough has not been kneaded to form gluten, the gliadin is still a problem.

It is possible to find “wheat flour” which has had the gliadin removed, such as Caputo Fioreglut. This would be ideal for a wheat-tasting pie crust, I think.

Comment: Before you serve this to somebody with gluten sensitivity, ask them if it's OK for them. First, sensitivity comes in different degrees, and sometimes micrograms of gluten can precipitate a crisis. Second, there are people who are allergic to some other wheat component but say they must eat gluten-free either because they have never discovered the subtle difference, or because it's just easier to say "I need gluten-free food" than go into the details of it.